# Nike brand pronounced /ˈnʌɪk/ instead of /ˈnaɪki/? BrE? Or?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

I've only ever known Nike to be pronounced as /ˈnaɪki/.

Recently, I've heard many BrE speakers exclusively read the brand as: /ˈnʌɪk/.

Do all BrE speakers pronounce Nike in this way? Is it a regional thing? Or a generational thing?

If you go through the list on Forvo: [Nike](https://forvo.com/word/nike/#en). Almost every English speaker reads Nike as /ˈnaɪki/ apart from the one BrE recording.

Comment: [US v UK correct way to pronounce Nike](https://www.goal.com/en-us/news/how-do-you-pronounce-nike-us-vs-uk-what-is-the-right-way-to/1tvtrn84fhk8d1bnblll0k40vv)

Comment: What is a correct pronunciation? The company says it is pronounced as two syllables no matter where you are. Lots of people pronounce it differently, because they've seen it written and heard other people pronounce it differently, and either don't know better or just want to fit in. IMO young people are more likely to pronounce it correctly (Greek-style) because they are more exposed to the culture around sportswear and clothes brands generally, but it will also depend on how your friends pronounce it and how much TV you watch.